# Laravel passport get token from database

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am using a Laravel version 5.5 and using Passport for authentication.
I have created token using:

```
$token = $user->createToken('string')->accessToken;
```

it generates the **token with 1075 characters** with the entry in `'oauth_access_tokens'` table having the **id of 80 characters**.

How can I get the 1075 character token from the database using the using 80 character token?

Comment: I think that you can access to the user tokens with $user->tokens()->get() but I do not sure If It is that you are looking for

Comment: @sochas `$user->tokens` is same as `$user->tokens()->get()`, and you will get records from oauth_access_tokens table, where will be that id of 80 characters, but @user10790140 wants to get real access token

Answer (score 0):

I haven't managed to find a way to get access_token from my passport, but I found the solution to generate a token on your own. It's part of the issues on Github. You could check the solution in the link, hopefully, it worked for me.

[Passport link to issue](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/779)

You could also check the generation of access_token in the passport repository [link](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/7.0/src/Bridge/AccessTokenRepository.php#L51)

Answer (score 0):

(This was tested on Laravel 8).

The code used to generate the JWT token can be found in `League\OAuth2\Server\Entities\Traits\AccessTokenTrait`.

which looks like this:

```
/**
     * Generate a JWT from the access token
     *
     * @return Token
     */
    private function convertToJWT()
    {
        $this->initJwtConfiguration();

        return $this->jwtConfiguration->builder()
            ->permittedFor($this->getClient()->getIdentifier())
            ->identifiedBy($this->getIdentifier())
            ->issuedAt(new DateTimeImmutable())
            ->canOnlyBeUsedAfter(new DateTimeImmutable())
            ->expiresAt($this->getExpiryDateTime())
            ->relatedTo((string) $this->getUserIdentifier())
            ->withClaim('scopes', $this->getScopes())
            ->getToken($this->jwtConfiguration->signer(), $this->jwtConfiguration->signingKey());
    }
```

Therefore in order to re-create your JWT token using the data found in `oauth_access_tokens` table, use the following code:

```
$oauthClientId = 1; // CHANGE! The ID of oauth client found in "oauth_clients" table
$tokenId = "..." // CHANGE! The 80 character ID found in "oauth_access_tokens"

$clientRepository = app(\Laravel\Passport\Bridge\ClientRepository::class);
$clientEntity = $clientRepository->getClientEntity($personalAccessClientId); 
$token = Token::query()->where('id', $tokenId)->firstOrFail();
$issuedAt = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $token->created_at)
            ->toDateTimeImmutable();
$expiresAt = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $token->expires_at)
            ->toDateTimeImmutable();
$scopes = collect($token->scopes)->map(function ($id) {
            return new \Laravel\Passport\Scope($id);
        })->all();

$jwtConfiguration = \Lcobucci\JWT\Configuration::forAsymmetricSigner(
            new Sha256(),
            LocalFileReference::file(Passport::keyPath('oauth-private.key'), ''),
            InMemory::plainText('')
        );

$jwtToken = $jwtConfiguration->builder()
            ->permittedFor($clientEntity->getIdentifier())
            ->identifiedBy($tokenId)
            ->issuedAt($issuedAt)
            ->canOnlyBeUsedAfter($issuedAt)
            ->expiresAt($expiresAt)
            ->relatedTo((string)$token->user_id)
            ->withClaim('scopes', $scopes)
            ->getToken($jwtConfiguration->signer(), $jwtConfiguration->signingKey());

$token = (string)$jwtToken;
```