# How to get access token from oauth_access_tokens in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

Is there any way to get the access token base on the `oauth_access_tokens` table id? I want to find a solution to solve the token problem.

[image: token table]

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to get access token from DB table - https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/779 (read the issue)
And there is also answer on SO - [Laravel passport get token from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53779404/laravel-passport-get-token-from-database)

P.S. this question should be marked as duplicate